# How do I express efficient JOINs by fusing SHUFFLE and COMBINE?

Tags: apache-spark

I apologize in advance for the long read. Your patience is appreciated.

I have two rdds `A` and `B`, and a `reducer` class.

`A` contains two columns (`key`, `a_value`). A is keyed - no key in the `key` column occurs more than once.

`B` has two columns (`key`, `b_value`)- but is not keyed, the key field can be repeated multiple times. And a few keys could be heavily skewed - lets call them **hot keys**.

The reducer is constructed using the `a_value` and can consume `b_values` of the corresponding key in **any order**. Finally, the reducer can produce a `c_value` that represents the reduction.

Example usage of the reducer looks like this(pseudo-code):

```
reducer = construct_reducer(a_value)
for b_value in b_values:
    reducer.consume(b_value)
c_value = reducer.result()
```

I want to use the tables `A` and `B` to produce tables `C` that contains two columns (`key`, `c_value`).

This can be done trivially by doing

1. calling `reduceByKey` on B to produce rdd with two columns `key, list[b_values]`
2. join with A on key
3. execute the code block above to produce the table with columns `key, c_value`

The **problem** with that approach is that the **hot keys** in `B` cause `reduceByKey` to OOM even at very high executor memory.

Ideally what I would want to do, is to join and immediately `reducer.consume` `b_value`s from `B` **into** `A` - the reducer is constructed from `a_value`s. Another way to think of this is to use `aggregateByKey` but with different `zeroValues` obtained from another rdd.

How do I express that?  (I looked at cogroup and aggregateByKey without any luck)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you try using `repartition(numPartitions)`  or `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(partitioner)` before you call `reduceByKey` on RDD B? Alternatively, use `reduceByKey(func, [numPartitions])`. In my experience, this helps in handling data-skew. Refer [RDD transformations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations)

Comment: @suj1th not if there is a hotkey, it will just blow up(OOM) the reduce.